# Reusing fd via close/open in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to track the connection of the joystick in Linux in an infinite loop and work with it while it is connected.

```
  device = "/dev/input/js0";
  while (true) { //loop
    js = open(device, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (js == -1) {
        perror("Could not open joystick");
        close(js);
        errsv = errno;
        printf("open result: %d\n", errsv);
        sleep (1);
        continue; //try again
    }
```

If I run the program with the joystick disabled and plug it in, everything works as it should. If I further unplug it and plug it back in, I get errno 9 (bad file descriptor) when I try to read again

```
bytes = read(fd, event, sizeof(*event));
errsv = errno;
printf("read result: %d\n", errsv);
```

I expected that closing the handle and reopening would allow further work with the joystick, but this is not the case. The re-joystick works only when the program is restarted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please note that `errno` is only valid *directly* after the failed function call. Any other function you call might invalidate it. That includes calling both `perror` and `close`. Also, if `open` fails, there's no need to call `close`. In fact, passing an invalid descriptor (like `-1`) to `close` *will* cause `close` to fail and set modify `errno`.

Comment: Also please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: If I'm not misreading the code you (try to) open the joystick over and over again without closing it. Not sure how that works. If this is indeed the code, there is no intervening sleep wither in the case of a successful open. Ah well, the closing brace for the loop is missing, so maybe you use the file descriptor after the open.

Comment: And @Someprogrammerdude is right: Post a minimal but complete example. My hunch is that you get an error while working with the successfully opened joystick, and then jump to the beginning of the loop trying to open it again. Then maybe you *should* try to close the obsolete file descriptor.

Comment: You don't get "bad file descriptor" errors unless you closed the file descriptor or the number wasn't a file descriptor to begin with. The clue is it says bad file *descriptor*, not bad file. It's 100% of the time a bug in your programming.

Comment: @user253751 As some programmer dude said: That erno is probably set by `close(-1)`.

Comment: A better pattern is to use `errno` only to detect *which* error occurred, and to rely instead on your functions' direct reporting mechanisms (usually based on their return values) to determine whether an error occurred at all.  Check `errno` only when you have reason to do so.  And note also that you need to pay attention to the error behavior of the specific functions you are calling, because there are some that, for example,  don't set `errno` at all, but instead *return* an error number on error.

Comment: im sorry, full text of code is here: https://pastebin.com/idB9G7Rm

Answer (score 2):

You should not look into the contents of `errno` unless a system/library call that has been documented to set it on failure, fails, and returns an error code.

`read(2)` won't overwrite `errno`'s value if it succeeded, in which case printing out it's value would result in an old error code, 0 or perhaps some garbage.

Here, the old `errno` code comes from `close(2)`. File descriptors are non-negative integers. Passing -1 to `close(2)` as you do here:

```
if (js == -1) {
    perror("Could not open joystick");
    close(js);
```

is sure to result in `EBADF`.

Here's how you may detect a `read(2)` error:

```
bytes = read(fd, event, sizeof(*event));
if (bytes == -1) {
    /* read(2) failed, handle error here. */
    perror ("read()");
}
```

Comment: This is all good information and advice, but it's not clear to me whether it addresses the OP's primary question, which is about reconnecting to the joystick device.

Comment: The primary concern seemed to be `errno`'s value. But if I'm wrong in that regard, my answer addresses one part of OP's question. So I think it would do. And hopefully, in the meantime, someone else would address the other part.

Comment: Well, the title of the question is "Reusing fd via close/open in C", which says nothing about `errno`.  And the closing remarks are all about reconnecting to the joystick, not about `errno`.  And the rest of the question also focuses on the joystick.  I don't see a reason to think that `errno` is raised for any reason other than to try to clarify the nature of the problem.  It may be that the semantics of `errno` are important to an answer to the question posed, but they do not in and of themselves provide an answer to that question.

Comment: full text of code here: https://pastebin.com/idB9G7Rm
im added "reset to 11" of errsv:
"
  while (true) { //loop \n
    errsv = 11; //reset"
but joystic events not work after reconnect

Comment: You have an infinite loop in which you keep calling `close(2)` if `open(2)` failed with -1 as an argument. And if you're not willing to check the return of library/system calls, you're just wasting yours and everyone's time. As of your claim, there is no `errsv = 11` statement in your code. I do not understand why you'd think that'd reset it. What do you want to reset?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

`bytes = read(fd, event, sizeof(*event));
errsv = errno;
printf("read result: %d\n", errsv);`


might not do what you think. That is, the read() function will set errno only if it detects an error, otherwise it won't touch it. Thus if the read succeeds you're printing out the errno value from the last time some C library function caused an error.

Comment: which is probably the close(js) when js==-1

Comment: Agreed, but it's hard to tell whether this addresses the OP's main question.

Comment: full text of code: https://pastebin.com/idB9G7Rm
I see that errsv is not updated, since there seems to be no error opening js0. It's just that the joystick is not readable after reconnection, for some reason. Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

im remove `close();` and its work now, full text at `https://pastebin.com/eyXFeyn1`